# Got refused for a UK visa. Think they might have incorrectly interpreted bank statements

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, business-travel, nigerian-citizens

Last month I started working as a software engineering contractor for a company in the UK and I was invited over for an onsite meeting which holds for a period of 1 week this month.

I applied for a visa and thought I'd be rejected for not having enough ties to home country but I just got the templated rejection of "large and irregular" deposits and I am surprised, to say the least.

My contract (which I provided) clearly states I earn £4000 monthly and I provided statements of my Transferwise account and two Nigerian bank accounts. I also explained in the cover letter that I use Transferwise to receive GBP payments in Nigeria.

The Transferwise statement clearly shows I transferred a sum of ~1290 USD to one of my Nigerian accounts on the day I got paid last month. This is the largest sum that has been transferred to the savings account in a while because I have been unemployed for about 7 months. I stated in my cover letter as well that this account was my savings account and explained reason behind the period of unemployment.

I also stated that I use the other account to handle daily expenses and that I often transfer funds from the "savings" account to the "daily expenses" account. Bank statements clearly shows transfers sent from savings -> daily expenses account.

The only other "large" deposit happened on the daily expenses account and it was for #150,000 (about £318.731). But I don't see how this could be a basis for rejection as I explained in the cover letter that my source of subsistence during the period of unemployment was from savings I'd gathered from past jobs and occasional support from friends (the case for this £318).

I also provided previous employment contracts and copies of email conversations that led to them so they can see that I have indeed had multiple engagements in the past. I included letter from landlord confirming rent paid till 2020 and proof of dependent brother's current enrolment in a Nigerian University.

The only way this would make sense is if they didn't read/acknowledge the cover letter somehow? But that would be highly unlikely as they acknowledge the other documents I provided, including the sponsor invitation letter.

I don't intend to apply for another UK visa anytime soon because the entire process is ridiculous and annoying. But I'd like to know what else I could have done to better represent my financial situation if I ever apply to other countries with similar requirements to the UK.

[image: Reasons for refusal]

Comment: Generally I think people here will be more able to help if you upload a scan of the the refusal notice, with personal information blacked out.

Comment: This SE:Travel question is three years old, but contains a useful and still-valid presentation and graphs of whata UK ECO will look for in an applicant's financial records. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab I suspect that the erratic deposits and withdrawals in your accounts were not convincing to the ECO as a stable, predictable earnings record.

Comment: @DavidsupportsMonica I browsed SE:Travel extensively before I applied. As a matter of fact, I read that specific link you shared multiple times and had it open in a tab throughout the time it took me to apply. 
Ultimately, I think it was the period of unemployment that got me.

Comment: @Ifeoluwa It may have been so. Without seeing a copy of the refusal notice (which you could post here with personal details obscured), no one here can opine if it provides further clues as to the reason for refusal.